# How to print all values in a dynamically resizing struct? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a dynamically resizing struct[]. I ask the user for how many records he wants then make that many struct.Then I store the name and age info in the struct. The problem is when printing out that data i am only printing the last name and age the user input. I would like to print all the values.

```
struct Records
{
    char name [32] ;
    int age;
};
void program2()
{
    Records rec;
    int size;
    cout << "How many record would you like?";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "\n" << size;
    Records* a = new Records[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Whats the name for the Record: ";
        cin >> rec.name;
        cout << rec.name;
        cout << "What is the age for this record: ";
        cin >> rec.age;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << rec.name << rec.age;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not utilising your `struct[]` at all. On the other hand, why not use std::vectors?

Comment: You never store `rec` in your dynamically allocated array.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "resizing struct".

Comment: "I have a dynamically resizing struct[]" nope. Did you mean "dynamically sized" ? because there is nothing dynamically resizing in your code. c-arrays cannot change their size dynamically

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the variable `rec` has nothing to do with the array. To access the element at position `i` of your array, you'll need to use `a[i]`.

For example:

```
cin >> a[i].name;
```

or

```
cout << "\n" << a[i].name << " " << a[i].age;
```

Comment: or `Records& rec = a[i];` as first line in the loop, not worth an answer, but thats probably the fix that requires least changes

Answer (score 0):

No surprise - you are actually printing repeatedly the last record that you created (rec). Your last loop is not actually traversing the array.

Also, the first loop only creates a struct, but does not actually add it to the array.

What you are trying to do is actually easier and cleaner if you use vectors instead of arrays, adding each record to the vector using push_back(). This is the closest thing to the "dynamically resized array" that you are referring to (such a thing does not actually exist in C++, that's what vectors are for, amongst other things).

Have a look into doing it this way, and if you get stuck feel free to ask again, happy to help.